# How to Cache a Haskell Dependency to Speed Up Compilation Time?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

**Problem:** I'm working on a Haskell project that uses stack (+ nix). We have a dependency that takes 10+ minutes to compile. Every time we clean our `.stack-work`, we have to wait for this huge package to compile, and it's really hurting our project's efficiency.  The package name is `godot-haskell`, and here is how the package is depended upon in our `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps:
- godot-haskell-0.1.0.0@sha256:9d92ff27c7b6c6d2155286f04ba2c432f96460f448fd976654ef26a84f0e35a6,26290
```

**Question:** Is there a way for us to somehow cache this package (in stack, or even in nix) so that it locally never has to get compiled (or has to get compiled at most once, even if the `.stack-work` directory is deleted)?

Comment: I believe this issue was the reason Cachix was created - https://cachix.org/

Comment: Why are you removing `.stack-work` anyway? It shouldn’t be necessary in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

For the currently released Stack, the best way to make this happen is to put the extra-dep into a custom snapshot file instead of the `extra-deps` in the stack.yaml file. (The upcoming Stack release has a feature referred to as "implicit snapshots" which sidesteps this.) You can see an example of this in the Stack repo itself:

- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/stack.yaml#L1
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/snapshot.yaml